# FreeRDP, меняется раскладка клавиатуры

Tags: ubuntu, docker, rdp, dockerfile, vnc

Есть docker-контейнер на основе ubuntu18:04, в который я устанавливаю клиент `freerdp2-x11` и `tightvncserver`. К этому контейнеру подключаюсь с помощью Remmina по протоколу VNC, а затем, после ввода пароля, подключаюсь к удалённому рабочему столу с Windows 10. Параметры подключения к удалённому рабочему столу передаются в контейнер как переменные среды (параметр `-e`).
Код запуска контейнера:

```
docker run -d --rm --name main-check -e USER=**** -e RDP_IP=***.***.**.** -e VNC_RESOLUTION=1920x1080 -p 5901:5901 test-main:latest
```

Но после rdp подключения сбивается раскладка на клавиатуре (то есть вместо 'f' например печатается 'h' и т. д.). Внутри контейнера всё нормально, да и после подключения по VNC пароль вбивается без проблем. Так что скорее всего проблема в RDP-подключении. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать в такой ситуации? (Опция /kbd:0x<id> не помогла).

Скрипт в `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

###VNC settings
VNC_OPTIONS="-depth ${VNC_DEPTH} -geometry ${VNC_RESOLUTION} ${DISPLAY}"

DIRECTORY="$HOME/.vnc"
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"
fi
umask 0077
chmod go-rwx "$HOME/.vnc"
vncpasswd -f <<<"$VNC_PASSWORD" >"$DIRECTORY/passwd"
VNC_IP=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')
echo ${VNC_OPTIONS}
vncserver -kill ${DISPLAY} || rm -rfv /tmp/.X*-lock /tmp/.X11-unix \
|| echo "remove old vnc locks to be a reattachable container"
mkdir /root/.Xsession
/usr/bin/vncserver ${VNC_OPTIONS}

###Window for password
read_password() {
PROFILE_PASSWD=$(yad --width 300 --center --entry --hide-text \
--image "dialog-password" \
--text "Enter password \n <b>$1</b>:" \
--title " " --button=gtk-ok)
echo "$PROFILE_PASSWD"
}

USER_PASSWD=$(read_password $USER)
RDP_WIDTH=$(awk -F'[x]' '{print $1}' <<< $VNC_RESOLUTION)
RDP_HEIGHT=$(awk -F'[x]' '{print $2}' <<< $VNC_RESOLUTION)
echo $RDP_WIDTH
echo $RDP_HEIGHT

###Start RDP
xfreerdp /u:$USER /p:$USER_PASSWD /v:$RDP_IP:$RDP_PORT /cert-ignore \
/w:$RDP_WIDTH /h:$RDP_HEIGHT
```

Список переменных среды в Dockerfile:

```
ENV DISPLAY=:1 \
    VNC_PORT=5901 \
    USER=root \
    VNC_DEPTH=24 \
    VNC_RESOLUTION=1280x1024 \
    VNC_PASSWORD=password \
    RDP_PORT=3389 \
    RDP_IP=
```